# How to upload photo with text?

Tags: php, mysql

This is student profile info form and its working fine when I submit the form all data save in to mysql table perfectly but I want to upload photo with info

When I fill the form and attach the image after submit the form

No upload in image directory but in mysql table photo name save perfectly but not upload in to image folder.

How can I do this please help me to fix this issue ?

submit Form

```
 <form action="" method="post">
 <div>
   <p><span class="style9"><strong>G.R.N No:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
     <input name="grn" type="text" value="<?php echo $grn; ?>" size="50" />
   </p>
   <p><span class="style9"><strong>Name:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
     <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" size="50" />
   </p>
   <p><span class="style9"><strong>Home Address:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
     <textarea name="address" cols="50"><?php echo $address; ?></textarea>
   </p>
   <p><span class="style9"><strong>Father Name:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
     <input name="fathername" type="text" value="<?php echo $fathername; ?>" size="50" />
   </p>
      <p><span class="style9"><strong>Mother Name:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
     <input name="mothername" type="text" value="<?php echo $mothername; ?>" size="50" />
    </p>
    <p><span class="style9"><strong>Date Of Birth :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
      <input name="age" type="text" value="<?php echo $age; ?>" size="50" />
   </p>
      <p><span class="style9"><strong>Religion :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
        <input name="religion" type="text" value="<?php echo $religion; ?>" size="50" />
   </p>
   <p><span class="style9"><strong>Parents Cell No :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
     <input name="phoneno" type="text" value="<?php echo $phoneno; ?>"/>
   </p>
   <p><strong>Home Phone No:</strong>
     <input name="phoneno2" type="text" value="<?php echo $phoneno2; ?>" />
   </p>
   <p><span class="style9"><strong>Date Of Join :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
     <input id="fullDate" name="dateofjoin" type="text" value="<?php echo $dateofjoin; ?>" size="50" />
   </p>
    <p><span class="style9"><strong>Class :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
      <input  name="class" type="text" value="<?php echo $class; ?>" size="50" />
   </p>
    <p><span class="style9"><strong>N.I.C :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
      <input name="nic" type="text" value="<?php echo $nic; ?>" size="50" />
   </p>
    <span class="style9"><strong>Branch:</strong></span><strong> *</strong>
    <input name="branch" type="text" value="<?php echo $branch; ?>" size="50">
<span class="style9"><strong>Photo:</strong></span><strong> *</strong>
             <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
            <input type="file" name="photo"> 
    <br/>
   <p class="style1">* required</p>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </div>
 </form>
```

php code

```
<?php 
 }


 //This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "images/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form

$photo=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}

 // connect to the database
 include('connect-db.php');



 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, start to process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $grn = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['grn']));
 $name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
 $address = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']));
 $branch = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['branch']));
 $phoneno = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phoneno']));
 $phoneno2 = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phoneno2']));
 $fathername = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fathername']));
 $mothername = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['mothername']));
 $age = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['age']));
 $religion = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['religion']));
 $nic = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['nic']));
 $class = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['class']));
 $dateofjoin = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['dateofjoin']));
 $photo = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['photo']));

 // check to make sure both fields are entered
 if ($grn == '' || $name == '' || $address == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 // if either field is blank, display the form again
 renderForm($grn, $name, $address, $branch, $phoneno, $phoneno2, $fathername, $mothername, $age, $religion, $nic, $class, $dateofjoin,$error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
  mysql_query("INSERT admission SET grn='$grn', name='$name', address='$address', branch='$branch', phoneno='$phoneno', phoneno2='$phoneno2', fathername='$fathername', mothername='$mothername', age='$age', religion='$religion', nic='$nic', class='$class', dateofjoin='$dateofjoin', photo='$photo'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 echo "<center>Admission Complete!</center>";
 // once saved, redirect back to the view page

 }
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, display the form
 {
 renderForm('','','','','','','','','','','','','','');
 }




?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the folder permission into which you are uploading image?

Comment: see full tutorial here..`http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp` for image upload and check permission for your upload folder..

Comment: this is localhost and no permission setting not allow in pc

Comment: check the tutorial you are missing something..enctype is missing i guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enctype = multipart/form-data` is missing in your form tag ...
`$_FILES` array will not get populated if you dont have `enctype` set.
so use

```
<form action="" method="post"> to <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

check for the folder permissions and the following settings in php.ini

```
file_uploads
upload_max_filesize
max_input_time
memory_limit
max_execution_time
post_max_size
```

When you use this you cannot access file's information using `$_POST` but only by `$_FILES` like `$_FILES['photo']['name']`

**FIX**

REPLACE

```
$photo = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['photo']));
```

with

```
$photo = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_FILES['photo']['name']));
```

Answer (score 2):

change `<form action="" method="post">` to `<form action="" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">`

See this w3schools page for more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: when i change this now in mysql table not upload image name

Comment: yes beause now you can use file as $_FILES['photo']['name'] and not using $_POST